# How do I store firebase Auth data in firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I have a basic app running. There's just one button which is used to login with google and I want to store that user's info in firestore and then I want to map through every user and display every single user's which are signed in, in my app. Firebase auth is complete but I don't know how to store that user's auth info.Also I am using useContext to pass authorized users info.Here's the code:

Main Entry Level App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { User } from "./components/User";
import db, { auth } from "./firebase";
import { UserContext } from "./Contexts/UserContext";

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ user, setUser }), [user, setUser]);
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      // console.log(user);
      setUser(user);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
      {user ? <User /> : <Login />}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

User.js Component

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../Contexts/UserContext";
import db, { auth } from "../firebase";

export const User = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <>
      <img src={user.photoURL} alt={user.displayName} />
      <div>{user.displayName}</div>
      <div>{user.email}</div>
      <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Log Out</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../Contexts/UserContext";
import { auth, signInWithGoogle } from "../firebase";

const Login = () => {
  const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      setUser(user);
    });
  });
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
          <img
            src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/20/000000/google-logo.png"
            alt="google icon"
          />
          <span> Continue with Google</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

signInWithGoogle

```
export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider).catch((err) => alert(err.message));
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `then()` block in your `signInWithGoogle()` function, as follows:

```
export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    const userId = result.user.uid;
    // Create a doc in a users collection
    // It's up to you to build the JavaScript object to pass to the set() method
    firestore.collection("users").doc(userId).set( {foo: bar, bar: foo} );
  })
  .catch((err) => alert(err.message));
};
```

More details in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithpopup).